# How would you handle two identical value objects that might differ in the future?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop

Let's say we have one Value Object in our Spring Boot app. It's a very simple VO with two fields, getters, setters, and one or two basic static methods. Another value object is required, which has the same structure at the moment, but it might differ in the future. How would you handle this situation?

Although they are programmatically identical, they should be used in different parts of the app. I want to be prepared for the changes in those two objects? Making two identical classes sounds too basic. Every question or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What is the likelihood that you will need to make this change?  How much work will it save you to support this feature now, as opposed to making the code change later when it's actually required?

Comment: Do they just 'happen' to have the same fields or are they really the same thing? If they just 'happen' to have the same fields, make them separate classes.

Comment: @azurefrog the odds of this change occurring in the future is pretty high, and due to the massive size of the app, it would save a lot of time.

Comment: @Jason they are meant to have the same fields at the moment, but I'm pretty confident that will change in the future, and I want my code to be flexible and easy to maintain and allow easy changes when needed, which is why I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this situation. The class that's already out there is used dozens of times and instantiated only through its static method, which calls a constructor, which is something I find pretty useful.

Comment: @soulzap What I meant by 'happen' was: are they supposed to represent the same conceptual thing, or are they different things that happen to have the same fields. If they are different things, they should be different classes.

Comment: If the current Value Object say X will remain unaffected and the changes will only be required to be made in the new Value Object say Y, then it is desirable to create a new Y object irrespective to their matching structure (currently). You also need to keep in mind that any change in the Value Object will possibly affect every single use case where it is used and that could break your code in the long run if you use the same object. It will also be easy to manage this new object and your existing code will not be impacted with adding a new Object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like two objects with an `IS A` relationship.
So, you use inheritance.

The second object extends the first one, so you have all the fields from the first one available for the first one.
Probably, you could make another supertype with `interface`, and move all your static fields/method into that.

Something like this.

```
public class FirstObj {
    private final String field1;
    private final String field2;

    public FirstObj(String field1, String field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

}

public class SecondObj extends FirstObj {
    // Any future fields...

    public SecondObj(String field1, String field2) {
        super(field1, field2);
    }
}
```

Comment: does creating two interfaces for FirstObj and SecondObj make sense, while keeping the original class and making it implement both interfaces?

Comment: it's even better to take out those static methods from the interface.
May be take all static methods into a Helper class?

Comment: @soulzap your main question and your question here on Sithroo's answer both need more context. What do these Value-Objects/Classes _represent?_ The similar _structure_ (two fields, getters, setters) is irrelevant — what do the things they represent have in common? Is one a particular type of the other (a cat is-a feline) so should inherit? or are they both different kinds of another thing (cats and dogs are both animals), so they should have the same _superclass?_ or do they share a common trait (both implement a common interface)?